# C# HTTP Request works in Console application but not in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Originally I created a console app to do some testing with getting api calls from a server and got that fully functional and working. Now, I want to make a display, but the same exact code from the console app will not function in the winforms app. Due to some breakpoint testing, I've seen that it gets hung up on this line:

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

I don't understand what the difference is, I have downloaded all necessary packages. I figure it has to do with using await. Thanks, Ethan

Here is the request method code with private information excluded. I realize there are some unnecessary components at the end, but I was simply copying and pasting from my initial test console application. All methods that use this method, including main, are async.

```
public async Task<string> APICall(string address)
    {

        string error = "An error was encountered.";
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), address))
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Api-Key", "API KEY");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/hal+json"));

                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Stream res = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                        using (var sr = new StreamReader(res))
                        {
                            using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                            {
                                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                            }

                        }


                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
                }

                request.Dispose();
            }
            httpClient.Dispose();
        }
        return error;
    }
```

These are the calling methods where the problem method is called, it goes from Main to startAsync to CallAsync, to APICall, the method in question.

```
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        Caller caller = new Caller();
        string test = await caller.CallAsync();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Server> server in Server.servers)
        {
            f.AddRow(server.Value.name, server.Value.location, server.Value.status, server.Value.ticketStatus);
       }
        Application.Run(f);


    }

public static async Task startAsync()
    {
        Caller caller = new Caller();
        string json = await caller.CallAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        dynamic name = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        List<Location> locs = name._embedded.locations;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (Location loc in locs)
        {
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Server.servers.Add(loc.name, new Server(loc.name, loc.address.city, loc.address.state, loc.id, loc.status, await caller.TicketStatusAsync(loc.id)));

        }
    }
        public async Task<string> CallAsync()
    {
        return await APICall(baseAddress);
    }
```

Comment: Did you get the response while in Console app?

Comment: Please provide some more context around the code.  What's the difference between the way that the console app calls this vs. the WinForms app?  How is `request` constructed, and what does it contain?

Comment: Just guessing... You have a [deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: I'm guessing some method directly or indirectly (via other methods) calling your method is not using await but `Wait()` or `Result` on it. This will block the calling task (usually the UI task) and thus await is unable to switch back to the UI task causing a deadlock. This won't happen in a Console because their is no synchronization context (UI thread) to switch back.

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing your method and calling method, but you could use `SendAsync(…).ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid context switching. But actually, async is meant to be async all the way up and calling Wait/Result should be avoided.

Comment: the same exact code, copy and pasted, works in the console app. I never call Result or Wait() anywhere in the Forms app, unless it is called indirectly without me knowing.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, further up your call stack, you are calling `Wait()` or `Result` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. In other words, your code is sync-over-async. This works fine in a Console app - and in fact, some blocking like this is *necessary* so the main Console thread doesn't exit before the asynchronous work completes - but it will deadlock in other contexts, including WinForms.

The reason it deadlocks is because `await` captures a context by default, and uses that context to resume executing the `async` method. So when your `await httpClient...` code runs, it captures the current context and then returns an incomplete task. Your calling code further up the stack will then block, waiting for that task to complete.

For the WinForms UI thread, that context is a `WinFormsSynchronizationContext`, which always executes code on the UI thread. So, when the `SendAsync` completes, it will resume executing the `async` method on the UI thread. However, that UI thread is blocked, waiting for the task to complete. The task cannot complete until the UI thread is free, so you have a deadlock.

The proper way to fix this deadlock is to [remove the sync-over-async antipattern](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). In other words, replace `Wait()` or `Result` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` with `await`.

Comment: Wait or Result are not called directly in any of my code. All methods using this method are async as well.

Comment: @Eman936: Then please post a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: @Eman936: A minimal, verifiable example needs to have all the code necessary so that someone else (i.e., me) can copy/paste it into a project locally and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Eman936: I don't see any WinForms code in your question; it looks like a Console app to me. I would recommend creating a new WinForms project and then adding your code (not including `Main`).

Comment: Does it matter that the OP does not call `Application.Run()` until after the async call? If I write a short Winforms app and check `Synchronization.Current` before calling `Application.Run()`, the result is `null`, so I assumed it isn't set up until the message loop is established.

Comment: Possibly. Different versions of WinForms behave differently. Some versions will ensure `SynchronizationContext.Current` is set after a control constructor; other versions will only set it after the Win32 window handle is created. @Eman936 It's best to assume you can't do anything async until an event is fired, e.g., Form Load.

Comment: Ok so I run the form and anything after Application.Run(form) doesn't run and I can't put an async method in the form... what am I supposed to do??

Comment: Why can't you put an async method in the form? That's the way it should be done. E.g., an async Form Load event handler.